# Quick excel chart question !

Tags: excel-2007

Hello guys I want to know how to make an excel chart from the following data.
From my website I am recording the usernames
user1
user1
user2
user3
user3
...
etc.

I want to just select this column in excel and in the the pie or bar chart i want to display the number of times each of these users have logged in. Is there any easy way to do this in excel?

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts at A1, in B1 put the formula

=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A1),"")

and copy it down the column

You don't have to sort the users, but if you have lots you may find it easy to read if you do.

That will get you the count, then you need to chart it.

You may need turn off the checkbox for:
Tools - Options - Error Checking - Formulas referring to Empty Cells